# Enable directory browing for ASP.NET projects published from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, http-status-code-403

I am trying to import an ASP.NET project which I know works and I am trying to build it on local. I imported the solution file in Visual Studio and went ahead and did a Clean and Build on it which went ok. Now I am trying to Publish the project and once I do that, I clicked the run button which says IIS Express and I see the following

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
```

If I was running this application out of IIS Manager, I know how to resolve this by clicking on the project, clicking Directory Browing and clicking Enable but I don't know how to fix this issue if I am running it from inside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue you could try one of the below ways:

1)Set the below code in the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

2)Set the default page for your project:

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <add value="pagename.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

if you are using the MVC site then set default routs.